# How Can I replace a div with another div(but of external html page)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want replace a div 'mainbox' that exist in html page 'index.html' with this that exist in html page 'list-div':

```
<body> 
    <div id="divet">
     Sempre caro mi fu quest'ermo colle,
     e questa siepe che da tanta parte dell'ultimo orizzonte
     il guardo esclude 
    </div>
 </body>
```

I did:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#mainbox').load('list-div.html #hey');
});
```

but it don't run.
Help me please.

Comment: maybe try ajax to receive the html. And  find the div in the response.

Comment: You are ordering `#hey`, but actually want to extract `#divet`. @Radonirina Maminiaina spotted that early on.

Comment: now I correct but it don't rame same

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<div id="divet">
     Sempre caro mi fu quest'ermo colle,
     e questa siepe che da tanta parte dell'ultimo orizzonte
     il guardo esclude 
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#mainbox').load('list-div.html #divet');
});
```

Your `#hey` id is not found, replace this with `#divet`

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var tempDom = $('<div></div>'); //create an element to store html
    $('div', tempDom).load('list-div.html', function(){  //load page content
        $('#mainbox').html($('#divet', tempDom).html()); //copy html content to mainbox element
    });
});
```

Comment: Why not just use a *bookmark-style* URL with load? It then does all this extraction/insertion automatically.

Comment: "Another" = "Longer"? "More complicated"? :) The only problem with the original code was having the incorrect id in the bookmark.